# Date Picker Using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I worte the code for my data picker to show in the text type having ID=target in codeigniter as this

```
$(document).ready(function() {                
$("#target").datepicker();                              
});
```

Then I got this error 
"$("#target").datepicker is not a function"

Comment: have u included relevant jquery files like jquery.js first and then datepicker.js

Comment: and what about jquery.js ? you need to include both jquery and datapicker.js

Comment: Check your javascript console for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple checklist (version numbers may vary):

- have you included jquery.js? (the main library)
- have you included jquery-ui.js? (the ui library)
- have you included jquery-ui.css? (the css for jquery ui)

That's 2 js files, and one CSS file to run jQueryUI widgets.

And you don't need datepicker.js. That's in the development bundle, if you want to fiddle around with their code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is javascript library conflict

Careful debugging